# Find out Conflicting Events using office365 Rest Calendar API

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, office365-restapi

I wanted to check that while creating new Event using Api need to check that is there any event present or create on same date and time.I mean how to check conflicting calendar event during creating new event using Rest API?

Any help must appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find the conflicts for the calendar event, we can use the Find meeting times feature (preview).

Here is an example for your reference:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/findmeetingtimes

Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-Type: application/json 

{ 
  "Attendees": [ 
    { 
      "Type": "Required",  
      "EmailAddress": { 
        "Address": "fannyd@prosewareltd.onmicrosoft.com" 
      } 
    } 
  ],  
  "TimeConstraint": { 
    "Timeslots": [ 
       { 
        "Start": { 
          "Date": "2016-05-20",  
          "Time": "7:00:00",  
          "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        },  
        "End": { 
          "Date": "2016-05-20",  
          "Time": "17:00:00",  
          "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        } 
      } 
    ] 
  },  
  "MeetingDuration": "PT1H" 
}
```

Refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#find-meeting-times-preview) about more detail.

Comment: Hi Fexi,as you told that by passing Start and End Date Time with API( https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/findmeetingtimes) the api response will be specific Event for that Date and Time,Suppose if Event is recurring (for example Event is scheduled every day @ 10 pm to 11 pm).so in this case i need to check it out like is there any one instance gets conflicted with another on same date and time.so for that this api calling will help us?

Comment: Find meeting time API suggestions based on organizer and attendee availability, and time or location constraints specified as parameters. You can get the free Timeslots in the response and use that time to create the new meeting. And which instance did you mean get conflicted with the recurrent meeting?

Comment: as of now my requirement is like this ,while creating new recurring meeting need to check is there  any meeting scheduled for that time.for example I want create Recurring Event with Every Monday @ 9 pm to 11 pm with 4 occurrences(i.e number of meetings).

Comment: But already meetings scheduled for weekday @ 9 pm to 11 pm with 20 occurrences.It means all 4 Mondays events will be conflicted.So before Creating or after creating the events,I need to come to know events gets conflicted or not.

Comment: I can able to do by pulling all available meeting from that calendar ,and by comparing events starting and ending date time .But here it will be very difficult if there are recurringmeetings counts are very high.

Comment: No. The findmeetingtimes REST is only apply to the none recurrent meeting. You can compare this REST method with **Scheduling Assistant** feature in Outlook. You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.